# "You cannot take a word out of a song"?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

There is a Russian expression "*из песни слова не выкинешь*", literally "*one cannot throw a word out of song*".

The meaning is that "*when telling a story, one may not omit even unpleasant/unsavory details*":

> ...during the interview he bad-mouthed his previous employers, he even call his former boss (sorry, *one cannot throw a word out of a song*), a 'bitch'...

or, more broadly, "*a coherent structure loses its coherence when critical parts are removed*":

> ...to prove this lemma, we need to consider seven cases; this is somewhat tedious, but *one cannot throw a word out of a song*, so let us begin with...

**What is the English analogue of this expression?**

[Russian proverbs](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Russian_proverbs#.D0.98) offered no "English equivalent" (I now added one, see below), just

> Meaning: You cannot alter the information that many people know by heart. — Also: The following may contain obscene, rude or otherwise questionable content, yet it content cannot be omitted as it's an integral part of the story.

What I tried:

1. [google translate](https://translate.google.com/#ru/en/%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C) - does not look like an idiom
2. [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C%22+english&oq=%22%D0%B8%D0%B7+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8+%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C%22+english&aqs=chrome..69i57.4354j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) lead to [academic](http://proverbs_ru_en.academic.ru/2368/%D0%98%D0%B7_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%88%D1%8C) which offers "*Pardon my French*" which reflects just the narrow meaning and, [eventually](http://translate.academic.ru/A%20word%20dropped%20from%20a%20song%20makes%20it%20all%20wrong./ru/en/), "***a word dropped from a song makes it all wrong***" which sounds idiomatic enough.

Comment: I've reopened the question. Thanks for fleshing it out.

Comment: Along those lines:  You can take the boy out of the country, but you can't take the country out of the boy.

Comment: As a native speaker of English, I think that it's a beautiful expression that I would use verbatim.

Comment: it's lovely as it is - I'd suggest trying to use it in English and see how it goes :)

Answer (score 1):

"warts and all" comes pretty close.

Said to derive from Cromwell's instruction to his portrait painter to paint an accurate picture including his facial blemishes, it's employed to describe a comprehensive analysis / consideration that takes pains to include all the ugly and unpleasant features, besides other aspects in order to get a full and honest picture.

"If we want to pick up the business we'll need to collect some in-depth warts and all feedback from customers and staff"

"To get through this we're going to need to talk honestly about where our relationship is at, warts and all"

[image: Portrait of Oliver Cromwell by Sir.Peter Lely]

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the existence of such a beautiful expression in English -- your suggestion of "a word dropped from a song makes it all wrong" could be a successful transposition of the original language, *providing* the context clearly explains what it means.

A translator could try:

- if the person said something rude:

> *and such were his exact words*
>
> *and I quote* (verbatim)
>
> *and I will not alter/omit a word of what he said*
>
> *please forgive my French* (colloquial)
>
> *I apologize, ladies present* (colloquial, dated)

- for information that people know by heart:

> *to use the time-honored expression*
>
> *as the saying goes*

Answer (score 0):

**"You'll have to take the good with the bad."**

But I like the original translation better.